# How do I update database without TryUpdateModel()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, nancy

I was using MVC4 all the time and I updated my entities to database simply by calling `TryUpdateModel();`

Example (MVC4)

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    var userDb = _db.Users.Single(x => x.Id == user.Id);

    if (TryUpdateModel(userDb))
    {
        _db.SaveChanges(); // Done, database is updated
    }
}
```

Now I'm using NancyFX for API and I don't have `TryUpdateModel()` function there.

```
Put["/"] = p =>
{
    var user = this.Bind<User>();
    var result = this.Validate(user);

    if (!result.IsValid)
    {
        return Response.AsJson(result, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    // How to update my database here? No TryUpdateModel() function is avialable.

    return Response.AsJson(user, HttpStatusCode.OK);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding, I would expect the following to work:

```
// get a fresh copy of the user model for the purposes of getting the id (there may be a simpler way to do this) 
var rawUser = this.Bind<User>();
// read the user from the db
var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == rawUser.Id);
// bind again, but using the db user as the target
this.BindTo(user);
// commit (I think EF may be smart enough not to do anything if BindTo() didn't actually change anything)
db.SaveChanges();
```